# List of "languages" to be used in "preformatted" code blocks for "Syntax Highlighting"

Tags: support, formatting, markdown, code

When I enter a "preformatted" code block in a body of Q or A, I have the option to specify the language of this code like this:

````
```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "something"
sleep 10
exit
```
````

so that the code block is colored (*syntax highlighted*) appropriately:

[image: syntax highlighted code]

I think the system can also color the code automatically by "guessing" about the contents of the code (I may be wrong about this).

Is there ***a complete list*** of all the "languages" (like `bash`, `c`, `python`, etc.) supported in *AskUbuntu*? There are cases where I do *not* want any coloring, like a simple text data; how can I indicate this?

Comment: have a look at https://highlightjs.org/  That is what is used.  Use "none" for no formatting and the system looks at the tags used.

Comment: note to readers: syntax highlighting doesn't work on meta, making this post slightly less easy to understand than it ought to be!

Comment: +3 to Rinzwind's comment - in particular, `none` is the most useful specifier of all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is here: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Note that `lang-plaintext` or `lang-none` explicitly disables syntax highlighting.

> *Quote from post edited 30 Aug, 2022.*
>
> ## Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange
>
> This is a complete list of every identifier that you can use in a
> language hint for syntax highlighting. All the language identifiers in
> each group point to the same highlighter. Other language aliases set
> by highlight.js (in brackets) should work, but only identifiers
> *before them* are officially supported by Stack Exchange.
>
> Format: **Language name: `lang-code`**,
> custom Stack Exchange aliases, (other Highlight.js aliases)
>
> - **Plain text: `lang-plaintext`**, `lang-none`, (`lang-text`, `lang-txt`)     (explicitly disables syntax highlighting)
> - **Bash and other shell scripts: `lang-bash`**, `lang-bsh`, `lang-csh`, `lang-sh`
> - **C and C-likes: `lang-c`**, `lang-cyc`, `lang-m`, `lang-c-like`, (`lang-h`)
> - **Clojure: `lang-clojure`**, `lang-clj`
> - **CoffeeScript: `lang-coffeescript`**, `lang-coffee`, (`lang-cson`, `lang-iced`)
> - **C++: `lang-cpp`**, `lang-cc`, `lang-cxx`, (`lang-c++`, `lang-h++`, `lang-hpp`, `lang-hh`, `lang-hxx`)
> - **C#: `lang-csharp`**, `lang-cs`, (`lang-c#`)
> - **CSS: `lang-css`**
> - **Dart: `lang-dart`**
> - **Delphi, Pascal: `lang-delphi`**, (`lang-dpr`, `lang-dfm`, `lang-pas`, `lang-pascal`)
> - **Erlang: `lang-erlang`**, `lang-erl`
> - **Go: `lang-go`**, (`lang-golang`)
> - **Haskell: `lang-haskell`**, `lang-hs`
> - **HTTP request/​response: `lang-http`**, (`lang-https`)
> - **INI, TOML: `lang-ini`**, (`lang-toml`)
> - **Java: `lang-java`**, (`lang-jsp`)
> - **JavaScript: `lang-javascript`**, `lang-js`, (`lang-jsx`, `lang-mjs`, `lang-cjs`)
> - **JSON: `lang-json`**
> - **Kotlin: `lang-kotlin`**, (`lang-kt`, `lang-kts`)
> - **LaTeX, TeX: `lang-latex`**, `lang-tex`
> - **Less: `lang-less`**
> - **Lisp: `lang-lisp`**, `lang-cl`, `lang-el`, `lang-lsp`
> - **Lua: `lang-lua`**
> - **Makefile: `lang-makefile`**, (`lang-mk`, `lang-mak`, `lang-make`)
> - **Markdown: `lang-markdown`**, (`lang-md`, `lang-mkdown`, `lang-mkd`)
> - **Mathematica / Wolfram Language: `lang-mathematica`**, `lang-mma`, (`lang-wl`)     (Mathematica SE only)
> - **MATLAB: `lang-matlab`**
> - **Objective-C: `lang-objectivec`**, (`lang-mm`, `lang-objc`, `lang-obj-c`, `lang-obj-c++`, `lang-objective-c++`)
> - **OCaml, F#, SML and other ML-family languages: `lang-ocaml`**, `lang-fs`, `lang-ml`
> - **Perl: `lang-perl`**, `lang-pl`, (`lang-pm`)
> - **PHP: `lang-php`**
> - **PHP template (HTML+PHP): `lang-php-template`**
> - **Protocol Buffers: `lang-protobuf`**
> - **Python: `lang-python`**, `lang-py`, `lang-cv`, (`lang-gyp`, `lang-ipython`)
> - **R, S: `lang-r`**, `lang-s`
> - **Ruby: `lang-ruby`**, `lang-rb`, (`lang-gemspec`, `lang-podspec`, `lang-thor`, `lang-irb`)
> - **Rust: `lang-rust`**, `lang-rc`, `lang-rs`
> - **Scala: `lang-scala`**
> - **Scheme, Racket: `lang-scheme`**, `lang-scm`, `lang-ss`, `lang-rkt`
> - **SCSS: `lang-scss`**
> - **Shell session: `lang-shell`**, (`lang-console`, `lang-shellsession`)
> - **SQL: `lang-sql`**
> - **Swift: `lang-swift`**
> - **TypeScript: `lang-typescript`**, (`lang-ts`, `lang-tsx`)
> - **Visual Basic (.NET), VBScript: `lang-vbnet`**, `lang-vb`, `lang-vbs`
> - **VHDL: `lang-vhdl`**, `lang-vhd`
> - **XML, HTML and their derivatives: `lang-xml`**, `lang-html`, `lang-xsl`, (`lang-xhtml`, `lang-rss`, `lang-atom`, `lang-xjb`,
>   `lang-xsd`, `lang-plist`, `lang-wsf`, `lang-svg`)
> - **YAML: `lang-yaml`**, (`lang-yml`)

Comment: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md  has a list of all

Comment: Thanks. `lang-plaintext` was what I was looking for! :)

Comment: ... and strange enough these codes do not work in meta.askubuntu.com I think!

Comment: @FedKad yeah it seems they don't. 